# vector element, accessed through raw pointer, unexpectedly changes value

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

Unexpected behavior of the following program (as short as I could make it):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Entry;

class CachedPayload {
public:
    CachedPayload(const Entry* const o) : owner_(o) {}
    void info(const char* where);
private:
    const Entry* const owner_;
    // meaningful payload not shown in this minimal example
};

class Entry {
public:
    Entry(int i) : cached(this), my_i(i) {}
    void showEntry(const char* where) const {
        std::cout << where << ": this=" << this << ", i=" << my_i << std::endl; }
    CachedPayload cached;
private:
    int my_i;
};

void CachedPayload::info(const char* where) { owner_->showEntry(where); }

class CachingVector {
public:
    CachingVector() {
        resize();
        data_.at(0).cached.info("GET");
    }
    void resize() {
        data_.push_back(Entry(97));
        data_.at(0).cached.info("RSZ");
    }
private:
    std::vector<Entry> data_;
};

int main()
{
    CachingVector vec;
}
```

Outcome:

```
$ clang++-6.0 h.cpp && a.out
RSZ: this=0x7ffe1dc52dc8, i=97
GET: this=0x7ffe1dc52dc8, i=4206609

$ g++ h.cpp && a.out
RSZ: this=0x7ffc5e977040, i=97
GET: this=0x7ffc5e977040, i=-578764228
```

Why is the value of `vec.data_[0].my_i`, when accessed through `vec.data_[0].cached.owner_`, overwritten in a nonsensical, compiler-dependent way?

When I merge the two-line implementation of `CachingVector::resize()` into the constructor `CachingVector()`, then `i=97` stays uncorrupted.

Comment: A raw pointer to the underlying array of a vector may be invalidated by any mutating operation such as `resize`, `push_back`, etc. This is an unsafe design for the exact reason you just illustrated

Comment: Thank you. Sounds pertinent. I changed the title of my question accordingly. What exactly you mean by »underlying array of a vector«?

Comment: @JoachimW internally the vector is allocating some space for it's elements. To simplify, a `std::vector<int>` could initially do `new int[4]` to allocate space for 4 ints. When you attempt to push_back the fifth int, it will double its size doing `new int[8]`, then copy all of the existing elements into the newly allocated space **then `delete` the smaller array** and continue to use the new one. Any pointers you had into the old array may become invalid any time you do an operation that could cause the vector to change size.

Comment: A `vector` is essentially just a wrapper around a dynamic array (like `new float[]`). Whenever you do something to resize the vector, it may need to reallocate that array if the current array doesn't have enough space. This means another `new[]` call, copying the old elements to the new address, then `delete[]` the old array. Therefore your pointer to the original array is now a dangling pointer that references deleted memory.

Comment: @CoryKramer It's not due to vector reallocation. Adding data_.reserve(1) prevents reallocation but the problem persists. The real issue is that a pointer to a temporary is being stored in the vector, once the temporary has been destroyed the value appears to change.

Comment: @john, where's the temporary?

Comment: For added fun, say you have {1,2,3}, get a pointer to 3, and then `erase` 2.. Read the value at your pointer and you may still get 3, even through the vector now contains  {1,3} and your pointer is pointing to  the location that USED to hold 3. You may not even know you've made a mistake until you push another number back and overwrite the pointed-at element

Comment: @JoachimW `Entry(97)`

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Any idea how to save the basic idea of my data structure? Somehow CachedPayload needs to know which array element it belongs to.

Comment: @JoachimW I think you just need a proper copy constructor and assignment operator on `Entry`. e.g. `Entry(const Entry& rhs) : cached(this), my_i(rhs.my_i) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to a temporary in your vector (specifically in `CachedPayload::owner_`). That's the cause of the problem. Once the temporary has been destroyed you have a dangling pointer.

I added this to your code

```
~Entry() { std::cout << "destroyed " << this << std::endl; }
```

and this

```
CachingVector() {
    data_.reserve(1); // prevent reallocation
    resize();
    data_.at(0).cached.info("GET");
}
```

New output is

```
destroyed 00000000001AF588
RSZ: this=00000000001AF588, i=97
GET: this=00000000001AF588, i=-858993460
```

As you can see you are accessing an object which has been destroyed, which is undefined behaviour of course.

To fix this I think you just need to define a copy constructor and assignment operator for `Entry` that make sure `cached.owner_` always has the correct value.

```
Entry(const Entry& rhs) : cached(this), my_i(rhs.my_i) {}
Entry& operator=(const Entry& rhs) { my_i = rhs.my_i; return *this; }
```